# AngularJS directive accept parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I want to convert the following code into directive:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="../images/icons/apple.svg" class="icon"></object>
```

So I could call it like:

```
<sicon type="apple"></sicon>
<sicon type="banana"></sicon>
<sicon type="orange"></sicon>
```

I tried:

```
  .directive('sicon', function(){
    return{
      restrict: 'E',
      scope:{
        type: '=type'
      },
      template: '<object type="image/svg+xml" data="../images/icons/'+type+'.svg" class="icon"></object>'
    };
  })
```

But did not work

Answer (score 2):

You should use `template` function in directive. No need to put value inside isolated scope, as it seems to be an hard coded value

```
template: function(ele, attrs){
   return '<object type="image/svg+xml" data="../images/icons/'+attrs.type+'.svg" class="icon"></object>'
}
```

For dynamic value from isolated scope, it will look below

```
template: '<object type="image/svg+xml" data="{{\'/images/icons/\'+type+\'.svg}}" class="icon"></object>'
```